# Retrieve Class element from Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the autodividersSelector function to display post date as divider text. I am stuck at the point of how to navigate to retrieve the date class. Below is the code and console log of the Div element in DOM.

If this question had been answered else where, please provide me with the link. Thanks

**Code**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/?json=recentstories" ,
        dataType: "json" ,
        beforeSend: function () {$('.loader').show();},
        complete: function () {$('.loader').hide();},
        success: function (data){
            $('#postlist').empty();
            //setTimeout(function(){
                $.each(data.posts, function (key, val) {
                //Format date
                var dateString = val.date.split(' ')[0];
                var vdate = dateString.split("-")[1] + " " + monthStrings[parseInt(dateString.split("-")[1])] + ", " + dateString.split("-")[0];
                //Output data collected into page content
                    var rtitle = $('<p/>', {'class' : 'vTitle', html: val.title}); rdate = $('<p/>', {'class': 'vDate' , html: vdate});
                    rid = $('<a href="#d-posts" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
                    var rappend = $('<li/>').append(rtitle, rdate);
                    $('#postlist').append($(rappend).wrapInner(rid).fadeIn(600));
                    $('#postlist').listview({
                        autodividers: true,
                        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                            //console.log(li);
                            var out = $(li).get(0)
                            console.log(out);
                            return out;
                        }
                    });
                    return (key !== 5);
                });
            $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh').append('<div class="more-posts" style="text-align: center;">Load more posts...</div>');
        //  }, 2000);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Service currently not available, please try again later...");
        }

    });
});
```

[image]

Result of output showing [objectHTMLLiElement] in the divider

[image]

HTML:

```
<!-- Page: Blog Posts -->
    <div id="blogposts" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h2>My Blog Posts</h2>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-role="listview">
            <ul data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder='Search blog posts...' data-theme="a" id="postlist"> </ul><!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="loader"><img src="css/images/loader.gif"/></div>
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.vDate').each(
    function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    }
);
```

Comment: why would you use `$(document).find` instead of just `$(".vDate")`?

Comment: @Ashkan I have just added my full code. I am still new to JQ & JS. Where would the document.find option sit in the code. Thanks

Comment: @JamesMontagne actually I wrote $('#the-parent').find('.vDate') to get spesific vDate , then changed it to document as I didn't know the parent he look for.  good point/

Comment: could you please explain more, what you want to do? you want to get the html of the .vDate element?

Comment: Yes for each posts, I want to get the post date with class vDate and use it as the divider text. Basically I want to group each posts by date of post

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I have added the output of the result. Can I get around this so it shows the actual Date. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code is fine but how would I get it to display on the divider

Comment: can you please add your html code, where is the divider? what is it? is it a div?

Comment: I have added the html code. The divider is only defined in the JS code and not in HTML

Answer (score 0):

OK this is the final code that worked for custom autodividersSelector:

```
$('#postlist').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
       var out = li.find("p").map(function() {return $(this).text();});
       var out1 = out.get(1);
    return out1;
    }
});
```